# Unchecked Assignment in java

Tags: java, generics, casting

I'm using the following code to find a one-dimensional list of unique objects in an n-dimensional list (credits to someone on StackOverflow a while ago for the approach):

```
public static <T> List<T> getUniqueObjectsInArray(List<T> array) {
    Integer dimension = getDimensions(array);
    return getUniqueObjectsInArray(array, dimension);
}

private static <T> List<T> getUniqueObjectsInArray(List<T> list0, Integer dimension) {
    List<T> list1 = new ArrayList<T>();
    return getUniqueObjectsInArray(list0, list1, dimension);
}

private static <T> List<T> getUniqueObjectsInArray(List<T> list0, List<T> list1, int dimension) {
    if (dimension < 1) return null;
    if (dimension == 1) {
        for (T listItem : list0) {
            if (!list1.contains(listItem)) list1.add(listItem);
        }
        return list1;
    } else {
        for (Object listItem : list0) {
            getUniqueObjectsInArray((List)listItem, list1, dimension - 1);
        }
    }
    return list1;
}
```

It works but I am still getting an 'unchecked assignment' warning when casting `listitem` to `List` in the following line

```
 getUniqueObjectsInArray((List)listItem, list1, dimension - 1);
```

Now I know I could just add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` and it would hide the warning. But is there a fundamentally different approach to doing this without this warning? Does it even matter in the end at all if this warning is there? Can fundamentally good code still contain warnings?

Comment: This is too much code, could you reduce it to the necessary minimum? The whole "find a one-dimensional list of unique objects in an n-dimensional list" seems completely irrelevant.

Comment: As for the question, the fact that `T` is a list in this case does not follow from typing in any way. The compiler will not be able to deduce this, so one way or another you will have an unchecked assignment.

Comment: Did you try List<?> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to get rid of that warning, as you you have to be very careful to declare and use the correct generic array types. So maybe you decide to ignore the warning...

- A 1-dimensional array with elements of type T are correctly described by your `List<T>` declaration.
- A 2-dimensional array is a list, containing lists of elements, so that should be `List<List<T>>`.
- A 3-dimensional array is a list, containing lists of lists elements, so that should be `List<List<List<T>>>`.
- and so on.

The very core of your search is the recursive `getUniqueObjectsInArray(...)` method. To get rid of the warning, you'd have to make sure that a call with e.g. `List<List<List<String>>>` produces a recursive (inner) call with `List<List<String>>`, and a dimension one less than before, so a first attempt would be something like:

```
public static <T,E> getUniqueObjectsInArray(List<T> array, List<E> results, int dimension) {
    //...
    for (T listItem : array) {
        getUniqueObjectsInArray(listItem, results, dimension - 1);
    }
}
```

That also won't work, as the compiler won't allow you to do the recursive call, as he can't make sure that the listItem is a List. Let's try to tell him that by:

```
public static <T,E> getUniqueObjectsInArray(List<List<T>> array, List<E> results, int dimension) {
    //...
    for (List<T> listItem : array) {
        getUniqueObjectsInArray(listItem, results, dimension - 1);
    }
}
```

Now he knows that it's a list, but now that isn't enough, as now you need a `List<List<whatever>>` for calling `getUniqueObjectsInArray(...)`.

You see, the attempts to do the right generics declaration so that the compiler doesn't warn, become quite complex, if at all possible. Honestly, I don't see a way to avoid the warnings, so don't spend too much time, and add @SuppressWarnings("unchecked").

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do not see the way to get rid of this warning since
you perform down casting `Object` to `List`.

In your case the item in the list *either could be some object or list*, and you don't have generics support or other language construct that could describe this fact.

So as I see it at some point you need to perform casting operation.

The difference though is that what you have now is not safe: how exactly are you ensuring that here

```
for (Object listItem : list0) {
    getUniqueObjectsInArray((List)listItem, list1, dimension - 1);
}
```

that `listItem` is a subtype of a List ?

What you can do is to try to bound you generic type and/or perform `instance of` checks to ensure correctness of the casting.

Answer (score 0):

You're implicitly casting all of your items in your list.

```
static <T> T findAnItem(List<T> items){

    return items.get(0);
}

    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    ints.add(0);
    Object a = ints;
    System.out.println(findAnItem((List<?>)a));
```

This example will compile without a warning because I am not casting the objects in the list to anything beside Object. If I switch `?` to `Integer`, then I get a warning.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are casting the object "listItem" to "List" without generic type parameters.

To get rid of this, just add the generic type parameters into the cast and it should get rid of the warning

```
(List<T>) listItem
```

Comment: I have already tried this. Casting to `(List<T>)` instead of `(List)` still produces the same warning.  `Unchecked cast:  'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.List<T>'`

Comment: It is actually the opposite of this. Casting listItem to List is fine, the unchecked warning is that all of the T's in the list are being implicitly cast.